# Does ConcurrentHashmap size() method count null keys?

Tags: java, maps

Lets say I have a `concurrenthashmap` with some keys and values that are not null. Later these keys can become null, then what happens? Are they automatically removed from `concurrenthashmap` or do they stay there as `null`? Does the `size()` method count them?

Comment: Could you please use a complete sentence? Your question is unclear as it stands.

Comment: well Lets say I have a concurrenthashmap with some keys(and values ofc and not null) , later these keys can become null, then what happens? they automatically removed from concurrenthashmap? they stay here as null? size() method counts them ? what?

Answer (score 1):

Most Java Maps can contain null values.

The following code is perfectly valid and will return a size of 1.

```
Map m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put("foo", null);
System.out.println(m.size()); //will print "1"
```

This is because HashMap allows for null values.

Turns out, however, based on my testing, that the following code will NOT work.

```
Map m = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
m.put("foo", null); //Will throw a NullPointerException
```

This is because, apparently, ConcurrentHashMap does not allow for null values.

According to the Javadoc(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Some map implementations have restrictions on the keys and values they may contain. For example, some implementations prohibit null keys and values, and some have restrictions on the types of their keys.

So, there you have it. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Just want to add that the javadoc for `ConcurrentHashMap` states this in no uncertain terms: "Like `Hashtable` but unlike `HashMap`, this class does not allow `null` to be used as a key or value."

Answer (score 0):

From ConcurrentHashMap API:

*Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value.*